# Ethernet to connect directly to device with static IP and no DHCP, Wi-Fi to connect to WLAN normally

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-3b+

I have a Pi3B+ (running Buster) that connects to my WLAN nicely via normal `wpa_supplicant.conf` means.

```bsh
~ $ ip -4 addr show | grep global
inet 169.254.60.134/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
inet 10.0.0.14/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
```

I'd like `eth0` to be able to talk to a device that comes pre-configured to:

```
dhcp: off
ip: 192.168.1.25
subnet: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 0.0.0.0
```

Ideally, I would directly plug in the device and be able to talk with it, but the device need not any internet access; just device-to-pi communication.

Is the right way to do this installing `isc-dhcp-server`? Can I set this up statically somehow?

I did try installing `isc-dhcp-server` following some similar-but-not-quite-the-same-use-case resources, but I ended up with the pi unable to "see" the internet (which I would like it to still be able to do via `wlan0`).

FWIW, if I set the device to have DHCP on and connect to a router on the same network as hosts the pi's WLAN, all works perfectly (which is probably obvious, but just to demonstrate that all the pieces basically work).

Ideas?

Thanks! :)

***Followup info:***

I started trying to set up a static IP, but wasn't having any luck... I'm sure it's my error.

So far in `/etc/dhcpd.conf` I've tried:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

...and...

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
static routers=0.0.0.0
static domain_name_servers=1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

...with no luck. Can you see what I'm getting wrong?

***Following up with more information:***

Currently in `/etc/dhcpd.conf`:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.1/24
```

Then here's what @ingo asked for:

```
~ $ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:6a:60:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c06d:1f08:cc48:4736/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:3f:35:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.14/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute wlan0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2ab4:1087:6f56:d4ad/64 scope link 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

~ $ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.14 metric 303 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.14 metric 303 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.1 metric 202 

~ $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
0
```

I'm thinking that seems good, but I still can't ping .25 from. the .1 pi. (This was an unrelated problem. See my answer for mistakes I made.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the information you have given I can't see why to install a dhcp server. It's also a bit dangerous if you don't know what you are doing because on a subnet (exactly on a broadcast domain) there **must** be only one dhcp server. That may conflict with an already running dhcp server on your internet router.

The simplest solution is to give interface **eth0** a static ip address of the subnet from the device, for example 192.168.1.1/24.

Comment: I saw that afterward... sorry... updated...

Comment: There is no connection to the internet on the subnet 192.168.1.0/24 so don't use entries for `static routers` and `static domain_name_servers`. Please paste the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` into the question when you have set the static ip address and rebooted. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` should return `0`.

Comment: Info is above... I re-edited it because I had a dumb off-topic problem in having mis-configured something while thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

@ingo was exactly right, and what he recommended worked perfectly.

All other problems I has were caused by thrashing prior to asking the question here.

Things I did wrong:

- Enabled predictable network interface names using `raspi-config`; "normal" is disabled, and enabling changes "eth0" into something presumably "random" and henceforth reliable.
- Didn't verify the IP address of the target device (the `192.168.1.25` device I was trying to talk with)